# Assistance Solving A Second Order Nonlinear ODE (Converted into a First Order)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the solution to $y''=y+y^2$

I noticed that if I multiplied by $y'$ on both sides and integrated, the result would be

$\frac{1}{2}(y')^2=\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{3}y^3+c$

I have almost no experience with nonlinear ODEs (they have this as a sort of bonus problem in the book I'm reading on linear ODEs) so I am not sure how to progress from here (I'm satisfied with solution where c=0, but would also like to see it where c is left there if possible)

Comment: Good job recognizing the integration factor for the first integration. The resulting first order differential equation is autonomous and [separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables). Simply integrate again to obtain an implicit equation for the general solution. To get an explicit solution you need to A) find an antiderivative for the 2nd integral if you can, and B) algebraically solve the implicit equation if you can. I say 'if you can' because for some ODEs this is impossible. For your particular ODE, I believe it's possible in principle, though difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $y''-y-y^2=0$. As you say, multiply by $y'$:
$$ y'y''-(y+y^2)y'=0 $$
But, this, by the chain rule, yields,
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \frac{1}{2}y'^2-\frac{1}{2}y^2-\frac{1}{3}y^3 \right] =0 $$
This is essentially conservation of energy if you think of the given ODE as Newton's Second Law. Of course, this brings us to:
$$ \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}y^2+\frac{1}{3}y^3}} = \int \sqrt{2} dt = \sqrt{2}t+c$$
At this point, in the classical vernacular, we have reduced the problem to quadratures, so, modulo some fun integration, we're done.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about separating it like above, but that does not  give the best answer. Any advice on any other approaches on making it look nicer, as in y= something, even if there is still some integrals involved? Or would it just look too ugly?

Comment: Well, that might be the best answer... I mean, it is not always possible to find an explicit solution for $y$. Granted, it is nice when we can. I'm not absolutely sure that integral can't be done, it just scares me currently. I'll feed it to wolfram alpha shortly. To my mind, these sort of problems do allow much analysis without an explicit solution. See around page 198 of http://www.supermath.info/DEqns2014.pdf I explain how you can study possible motions without even having the formula for the solution. Poincare or phase plane analysis very nice when paired with pplane in matlab

Comment: Amusingly, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F+%28\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}y^2%2B\frac{1}{3}y^3}%29+dy it can be integrated. That said, I don't think solving for $y$ will be possible. Except in the theoretical sense, the implicit function theorem gives the existence of a local solution and even a series of functions which iteratively converges to the local solution... but, this is not a formula in the sense that most of us would ideally desire.